# Are parenthesis considered as blocks in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, by definition a block is defined by a pair of curly brackets, but are parenthesis also considered as blocks?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  //some code
}

console.log(i) // outputs 5;

for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
  //some code
}

console.log(j) // ReferenceError
```

Comment: The `for` loop is a special case. The variables declared with `let` are considered to be scoped to the body of the loop

Comment: Another relevant bit is that [*var* definitions are hoisted to the top of the function or global code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting).

Comment: *"This expression may optionally declare new variables with `var` or `let` keywords. Variables declared with `var` are not local to the loop, i.e. they are in the same scope the `for` loop is in. Variables declared with let are local to the statement."* - [MDN for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for#Syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how `let` and `var` works in `for` statement.

[As mdn says:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

> This expression may optionally declare new variables with `var` or `let`
>   keywords. Variables declared with `var` **are not local to the loop**, i.e.
>   they are in the same scope the for loop is in. Variables declared with
>   `let` **are local to the statement**.

```js
let k = 15;
for (let k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
  console.log(`k is ${k}`);
}

// Here k is 15
console.log(`variable k which is declared above the loop ${k}`)
```

Comment: However in the posted code, the `let` is *outside* the `{ }` body of the `for` loop.

Comment: I think the OP knows that bit, he's pointing out the `let` is in fact outside the `{}`,.  but like Pointy has pointed out the for is a special case.

Comment: @Pointy oops, I've edited my answer. Please, see my updated reply

Comment: @Keith thanks for the great comment! I've edited the answer. Please, see my updated answer

Comment: @downvoter  I believe that there is no reason to downvote now. I've edited the answer. Please, see my updated answer:)

Comment: Not me either, but I do know w3schools has a bad rep here. :),  maybe an mdn link -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for  The part that relevant here -> `Variables declared with let are local to the statement.`